# A good (preferably free) installer for .Net apps?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I have a .Net (C#) app that uses Sql Express. Development is finished, and now i have to choose some installer to deploy my app. I tried "Microsoft Visual Studio Publishing Wizard" but i love it and hate it in the same time!
I love it cause it detects all components missing at clients computer, downloads them and installs them automatically.
I hate it cause once deployed, my app doesn't seems to have it's directory, so client can't place plugins he develops independently! Also, i don't know if i can tell "publishing wizard" to create particular dir structure inside installation folder...

Is there any installer able to detect missing components from my client's computer, download and install them and also allow me to configure installation path, dir structure and etc?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) which is great installer itself and with such scripts like [Modular InnoSetup Dependency Installer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-1-1-2-0-3-5-Installer-for-InnoSetup) (you can also write your own) you can install missing components.

Comment: GREAT! I'm familiar with Inno, it's my favorite, but i had no idea it could work with dependencies! Thank you, this "Dependency installer" looks promising.

Comment: Having used both Inno and Wix I have to agree with you.  The enthusiasm being shown for WiX is somewhat puzzling.  I found WiX to be an awful lot of bother to achieve even the simplest of installation tasks. Inno on the other I managed to learn to do what I needed within a day.  Perhaps need to read thye WiX  documentation more thoroughly, but for me its install/upgrade processes do not always behave in the way I wanted and I am left none the wiser.

Answer (score 14):

I suggest [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). It's free and very flexible.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't need all the bells and whistles (and the overhead that comes along with it) of WiX (and the MSI technology), but you want an easy to use, **free** and well tested installer, have a look at [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

It's small, it's reliable (has been around since 1997 and used in many apps), it's totally **FREE** - yes even for commercial apps! - and you can even get the (Delphi) source code for it from a Git repo to take a peek at its innards.

There's also quite a few add-ons to enhance its already great functionality.

Comment: InnoSetup is not "totally free", according to their site.
Note: "Completely free of charge" must not be confused with "completely free". Inno Setup is copyrighted software, not public domain software. There are some restrictions on distribution and use; see the LICENSE.TXT file for details.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer XML (WiX) creates MSI packages which uses the Windows Installer.

Visual Studio is just a WiX alternative, just another setup authoring tool but it only has some basic features.
h