# I need to know the procedure of creating a setup file

Tags: vb.net

I have developed an astrology software using VB.net. Now i want to install the software on other systems without using the class files. I wish to install that software using a setup. Could anybody please tell me how to create setup  file for my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A good (preferably free) installer for .Net apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954855/a-good-preferably-free-installer-for-net-apps)

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools to create setups. Setups can go from very simple to very complex: It all depends on what tasks you need.

I have been using the Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS). It's very flexible, free and well documented. It has some learning curve but you can start simple and add more complex features while you learn. Homepage is here: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/